# Is there a safe spot to store dynamically created Rails models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the following Rails 3 model to dynamically create models:

```
# encoding: UTF-8

require_dependency 'read_only'
require_dependency 'readings_methods'

class Reading < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  include ReadOnly
  include ReadingsMethods

  @@mutex = Mutex.new
  @@children = {}

  def self.with_table(t)
    @@mutex.synchronize do
      child = @@children[t]
      if child.nil?
        child = Class.new(self) do
          self.table_name = t
        end
        @@children[t] = child
      end

      child
    end
  end
end
```

Debugging shows, however, that `@@children` is reset on every page load, thus making every page load very, very slowly. How do I prevent this? And what is causing it? Unless I memoize children, Rails goes into infinite loop, which leads me to believe that it reloads at least some classes whenever I create a new model, or something like that. How do I prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails reloads code for you in development mode so that you don't have to restart the rails server every time you make a change (in rails 3.2 it tries to only reload the code that has changed).

When a class is reloaded, rails unsets the constant and loads a fresh copy, so in particular the new one will have a fresh set of class variables.

`ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_once_paths` and `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths` control what is reloaded in this manner. You should be able to add the (full) path to your file to autoload_once_paths to prevent that one file from being reloaded (but you will then have to restart rails so see any changes made to it )

Comment: But why is it reloaded on each page load? Is something in `ActiveRecord::Base` triggering this behavior?

Comment: If you're using < rails 3.2 then that's just the way it works. If you're on rails 3.2 then something is tripping the heuristics ActiveSupport uses to decide what might need reloading.